# How to add second background image in scrolling background (javafx)

Tags: javafx, background

I'm currently trying to program an easy Jump'n'run Game with JavaFx which basically works like doodle jump. However, I want the background to move down whenever the character jumps. But I want the second background image to appear at the top and also move down so there's no gap, if you get what I mean?
Right now, the method looks like that:

```
private void moveScreen() {
        backgroundPane = v.getBackgroundPane();
        newBackgroundPane = v.getNewBackground();

        if(verticalSpeed < 0) {
            backgroundPane.setTranslateY(backgroundPane.getTranslateY() + 1);
        }
    }
```

Right now, the first image moves down as it should, but of course the second is missing so there's just white space. So how do I add the second background image on top of the first one?